# Interpolation in Pandas horizontally independent to each rows

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a dataframe like this

```
ID,Time0,Sum0,Average0,Time1,Sum1,Average1
1,1520320347531.0,59.3635,18.2828,1520324772351.0,59.5031,18.4745
1,1519860442638.0,60.1159,20.3027,1519861181524.0,60.1033,20.31705
```

And I want to interpolate horizontally in every 5 mins.

this code interpolates perfectly if the data are arranged vertically but i am not sure how do I interpolate horizontally for that rows. Even though there are identical Ids in two different rows, I want to make interpolate independent to each rows.

```
df = df.set_index(['Time'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='ms')

df = (df.groupby('ID')[['Sum', 'Average']]
       .resample('5min')
       .mean()
       .groupby(level=0)
       .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate()).reset_index())
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: right now the data are divided in average of 10 mins and I want to resample in 5 mins. About the expected output,i am not sure yet, as this will be handled by pandas while doing interpolation of Sum and Average based on Time (5 min)

Comment: @user3280146 but do you want the output as rows (with many columns) or as columns, knowing that you want to interpolate between Time0 and Time1 from a same row?

Comment: I want the output as rows with many columns as long as it interpolate. Only requirement is rows interpolation should be independent to other rows even if Id is same. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer but it's a bit ugly, to anyone seing overmanipulation of the data, feel free to correct it.

First, from your data, I change the value `1520324772351.0` (first row, column Time1) to `1520321086417.0`, otherwise it's way more than 10 minutes and make the example with to many columns.

From your data, I first create a concatenated dataframe such as

```
df_concat = (pd.concat([df[['ID','Time0','Sum0','Average0']]
                                .rename(columns={'Time0':'Time','Sum0':'Sum','Average0':'Average'}),
                       df[['ID','Time1','Sum1','Average1']]
                                .rename(columns={'Time1':'Time','Sum1':'Sum','Average1':'Average'})])
                    .sort_index())
```

to get data like this:

```
   ID          Time      Sum   Average
0   1  1.520320e+12  59.3635  18.28280
0   1  1.520321e+12  59.5031  18.47450
1   1  1.519860e+12  60.1159  20.30270
1   1  1.519861e+12  60.1033  20.31705
```

Here you can use your method working for data in columns with groupby on the index column:

```
df_concat_set = df_concat.reset_index().set_index(['Time'])
df_concat_set.index = pd.to_datetime(df_concat_set.index, unit='ms')

df_concat_set = (df_concat_set.groupby('index')[['Sum', 'Average']]
                              .resample('5min')
                              .mean()
                              .groupby(level=0)
                              .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate())
                              .reset_index())
```

Here you have the data:

```
   index                Time      Sum    Average
0      0 2018-03-06 07:10:00  59.3635  18.282800
1      0 2018-03-06 07:15:00  59.4333  18.378650
2      0 2018-03-06 07:20:00  59.5031  18.474500
3      1 2018-02-28 23:25:00  60.1159  20.302700
4      1 2018-02-28 23:30:00  60.1096  20.309875
5      1 2018-02-28 23:35:00  60.1033  20.317050
```

In order to put it back to lines, I did this way (here I'm sure there is a pivot_table method that I don't know, but this way works):

```
#first create a column with incremental number within a group of index:
df_concat_set['level_1'] = df_concat_set.groupby('index').cumcount()+1
# then set index and unstack
df_unstack = df_concat_set.set_index(['index','level_1']).unstack(level=1)
# here you have multiindex columns so change it to one level:
df_unstack.columns = [col[0]+str(col[1]-1) for col in df_unstack.columns]
# then change the order of columns (if necessary)
df_unstack = df_unstack[[ s+str(i) for i in range(len(df_unstack.columns)/3) 
                                        for s in ['Time','Sum','Average'] ]]
```

your final output is:

```
                    Time0     Sum0  Average0               Time1     Sum1  \
index                                                                       
0     2018-03-06 07:10:00  59.3635   18.2828 2018-03-06 07:15:00  59.4333   
1     2018-02-28 23:25:00  60.1159   20.3027 2018-02-28 23:30:00  60.1096   

        Average1               Time2     Sum2  Average2  
index                                                    
0      18.378650 2018-03-06 07:20:00  59.5031  18.47450  
1      20.309875 2018-02-28 23:35:00  60.1033  20.31705
```

which is what I hope you want.

As I said, it's propbably overmanipulation, but I could not find another way.